# Why isn't this question a recommendation question?

Tags: discussion, closing-questions

The question asker didn't say he was interested in reading the books people listed, but what if he was?

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/works-of-science-fiction-featuring-as-of-yet-inexistent-narcotics-drugs

This question and it's answers is isomorphic with a request for recommendations for similar books, which is a question type that is getting close because scifi "isn't a recommendation service."

(Btw, I don't think it should be closed, because to mention a book, without specifically condemning it is to recommend it. But if we don't mention books, we can't talk about science fiction.)

**UPDATE: 20% of the front page questions are of this type. A bit higher if you include the already closed questions.** So 1/5 of all newbie questions will get closed.  When I started as a naive newbie on SO, I didn't have anything near a 20% close rate

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/935/sci-fi-that-leverages-contemporary-technology

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1156/works-of-science-fiction-featuring-as-of-yet-inexistent-narcotics-drugs

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/937/are-there-more-novels-like-daniel-suarezs-daemon-and-freedom

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/687/what-works-feature-humans-gaining-immortality-and-its-effects

[What Sci fi story featured a linear accelerator for space launch?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/609/what-sci-fi-story-featured-a-linear-accelerator-for-space-launch)

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/205/are-there-any-major-sci-fi-authors-that-share-a-universe-in-their-novels

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/1047/novels-like-larry-nivens-the-mote-in-gods-eye

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7/has-any-science-fiction-work-accurately-predicted-the-emergence-of-future-technol

Comment: Like Eight says in his answer. A list is a list. That's what wikipedia is for.

Answer (score 4):

It should have been closed, not made community wiki. CW is not an excuse to allow another set of poll or list type questions. Such proliferation renders the entire state of this Stack Exchange as iffy.

Still, it is a recommendation question dressed up as a list type.

Comment: **BIG NOTE:** Making a questions community wiki **in no way** suggests that the question is being endorsed as *allowed*. It only says that wiki is appropriate... should the question survive. I make questions community wiki as a minimum requirement, without necessarily judging whether it should be voted closed. **Quite the opposite**: Many of these wiki questions *should* be closed. I'm just not ready to remove a big swath of questions before you guys decide what this site is about.